# Driver for Integrated Display on Lenovo 420s Core i7

Tags: 10.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I am looking for the drivers for Integrated Display on Lenovo 420s Core i7. This computer has the nvidia optimus option. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which driver should I use? Nvidia's or Ubuntu's? \[Optimus related\]](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47085/which-driver-should-i-use-nvidias-or-ubuntus-optimus-related)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turnoff nvidia graphics card and use it only when required install **[The Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html)**:

If you are on 11.04 or older , you  will need new drivers, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
```

Add the Stable Bumblebee Releases PPA and install Bumblebee using the proprietary NVIDIA driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine, and run 11.10 Oneiric or later, you will need extra libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Allow yourself to use Bumblebee by adding yourself to the 'bumblebee' group. (replace `$USER` by your username)

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Reboot or re-login to apply the group changes

If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program:

`optirun firefox &`

Read more from [bumblebee wiki](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/)

Linked Question:

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)